# Bash command to select only specific actions from log files

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, logs, syslog

Hello there I have the following example for a log file below:

```
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:39 +0200|185.34.66.225|user_1| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:39 +0200|185.34.66.225|user_1| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:39 +0200|185.34.66.225|user_1| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:42 +0200|185.34.66.225|user_2| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:40 +0200|185.34.66.215|user_3| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:49 +0200|185.34.66.215|user_3| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:49 +0200|185.34.66.215|user_3| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:59 +0200|185.34.66.205|user_4| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:59 +0200|185.34.66.205|user_4| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:59 +0200|185.34.66.205|user_4| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:59 +0200|185.34.66.205|user_4| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:17:50 +0200|185.34.66.205|user_5| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:17:50 +0200|185.34.66.205|user_5| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:17:50 +0200|185.34.66.205|user_5| - |user changed profile| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:17:50 +0200|185.34.66.205|user_5| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 15:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|user_6| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 15:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|user_6| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 15:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|user_6| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:20:42 +0200|185.34.67.225|user_7| - |user logged in| -
```

I want a bash command or script to check and print each user "logged in then changed password then logged off" without doing any other action & in the same second so the output shall be:

```
user_1
user_4
user_6
```

any help would be appreciated

Update:
in the end I figured out how to do it but I want help of how to make it shorter and not to take much time with a huge log file:

**`cat /path/to/file | awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[3],a[1],a[5]}' | awk '{ print $6,$1,$8,$9,$10 }' | grep -A 1 -B 1 "user changed password" | awk 'seen[$1]++ ==2' | grep "user logged off" | awk '{ print $2}'`**

Comment: This isn't a script writing service. Please show us what you've tried. You should explain what it does and what it doesn't do, and present any error messages it generates.

Comment: What roaima said. Also, why only in the same second? What if the user logs in during the last millisecond of 12:01, and changes the password and logs out during the first few milliseconds of 12:02. The entire process would still only have taken a single second even if it is logged as having occurred in diferent seconds.

Comment: How about those cases where the user did lots of things, but they don't appear in the log?

Comment: actually it's from my class assignment and the tutor was specific on the requirement mentioned  in the question, the main idea to catch bots that login, change password, logout without doing anything else and in the same second ... till now I was able to filter the required fields but still trying to get further as below:
cat test | awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[3],a[1],a[5]}' | awk '{ print $1,$6,$8,$9,$10 }' | grep -A 1 -B 1 "user changed password"